# I have a 2000 ford contour 2.0 runs fine but will not get any faster then 40 mph no matter how much throttle I give,

Tags: transmission, fuel-system, electronic-control-module, catalytic-converter, motors

Motor runs fine transmission shits fine has full rpm range all gears but at 40 it will not run any faster no matter how much throttle you give

Comment: Take it to a parts store that scans codes for free and post them here.

Comment: Sounds like the vehicle is in limp-home mode, as there's a fault. As said, get a shop to scan for fault codes.